# I having trouble using partial fractions.

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-fractions

For the integral below I have to use partial fractions, however I am at a lost on how to do so.
$$\int\frac{dt}{t^2-t-20}$$

The farthest I have gotten to is factoring the denominator to $(t+5)(t-4)$. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the signs you wrote are wrong.

$$\frac{1}{t^2-t-20}=\frac{1}{(t\color{red}{-}5)(t\color{red}{+}4)}=\frac 19\left(\frac{1}{t-5}-\frac{1}{t+4}\right)$$

Comment: Where does the 1/9 come from?

Comment: @JMartinez: Setting $\frac{A}{t-5}+\frac{B}{t+4}$ gives you $\frac{A(t+4)+B(t-5)}{(t-5)(t+4)}=\frac{(A+B)t+4A-5B}{(t-5)(t+4)}$. Since this has to equal $\frac{1}{(t-5)(t+4)}$, you'll get $A+B=0$ and $4A-5B=1$. Solving these will give you $A=1/9,B=-1/9$. So, you'll have $\frac{1/9}{t-5}+\frac{-1/9}{t+4}=\frac 19\left(\frac{1}{t-5}-\frac{1}{t+4}\right).$

Answer (score 1):

When you have to solve something of the form:

$$\int \dfrac{dt}{(t-a)(t-b)} $$

Then you can have

$$\dfrac{A}{t-a} + \dfrac{B}{t-b} = \dfrac{1}{(t-a)(t-b)}$$

Wich means that

$$\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}A\ +B\ & = & 0 \\ Ab + Ba & = & -1 \end{array}\right. $$

Once you find $A$ and $B$ then

$$\int \dfrac{dt}{(t-a)(t-b)} = \int{\dfrac{A}{t-a}dt} + \int{\dfrac{B}{t-b}dt}$$

Answer (score -1):

**hint**: $\dfrac{1}{t^2-t-20} = -\dfrac{1}{9}\cdot \dfrac{1}{t+4} + \dfrac{1}{9}\cdot \dfrac{1}{t-5}$

Comment: This isn't a very good hint. It just gives the *result* of the partion fraction decomposition but doesn't how explain *how* it is done.